# How to call a function with structs as parameters?

Tags: c, function, struct

If I have a struct like this:

```
struct Point 
{
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

and a function like this

```
double geometricDistance(struct Point point1, struct Point point2)
{
    double xDist = point1.x - point2.x;
    double yDist = point1.y - point2.y;
    return sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
}
```

when I call `geometricDistance`, I can't just do `geometricDistance(5,6);` or something like that, because that's only two integers. How do I call it?

Thanks.

Oh yeah it's in C by the way.

Got it- use braces. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So you have your struct.

In main you can declare a point.

```
struct Point point1;
struct Point point2;
```

Now you made a struct variable called point that has access to both of those values double x and double y in your struct.

```
point1.x = 12;
point1.y = 15;

point2.x = 5;
point2.y = 6;
```

To pass it into the function you pass in a pointer to the struct, that lets you edit the value of that point.
    //function call
    `double value = geometricDistance(&point1, &point2);`

```
double geometricDistance(struct Point* point1, struct Point* point2)
{
  double xDist = point1->x - point2->x;
  double yDist = point1->y - point2->y;
 return sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
}
```

**Edit:** I realized that you don't actually need to pass in the pointer to the struct. you can simply make the function parameters `double geometricDistance(struct Point point1, struct Point point2)` since you're not changing the values of any of the struct variables you declared.
Your function call could simply be `double value = geometricDistance(point1, point2);` Inside of the function instead of using the `->` reference you can use the `.` reference like this `point1.x` or `point1.y`

Comment: the value returned by `geometricDistance` is a `double` not an `int`.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. I see now why pointers are used with functions and structs.

Comment: You have also changed the signature of the function. 
The arguments to pass are `struct Point`, not `struct Point *`.
If you want to use the pointers you have to change the body of the function, for example you have to use `point1->x` instead of point1.x

Comment: @GerardoZinno Thanks fixed it.

Comment: @Josh If my answer helped you solve your problem would you mind checking the check mark next to my post?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a variable of type struc Point.

For example:

```
struct Point A;
struct Point B;
//add values in the fields x and y if you need to
.
.
.
double something = geometricDistance(A, B);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two other categories that you should know about that are also referred to as "parameters". They are called "parameters" because they define information that is passed to a function.

```
Actual parameters are parameters as they appear in function calls.
Formal parameters are parameters as they appear in function declarations.
```

The definition/prototype of function `geometricDistance` shows that it needs two parameters of type `struct Point`. You just need to call `geometricDistance` function with two parameter of type `struct point`.

For example,

```
struct point a,b;
.
.
double result = geometricDistance(a,b);
```